# how can i get a specific nested object which satisfies a specific condition from a query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

```
Iam storing in elastic like this


{
  "user":{
           "name":"Johnson",
           "age":29,
           "education":[
            {
                "school":"STE college",
                "year":2017,
                "qualification":"Phd",
                "isRecent":1
            },
            {
                "school":"business school",
                "year":2015,
                "qualification":"Mba",
                "isRecent":0
            },
            {
                "school":"saint school",
                "year":2013,
                "qualification":"Btech",
                "isRecent":0
            }
           ]
     }
}
```

i need to get query data where age is 29 and match school as "STE college" only where education is recent (school="STE college" and isRecent=1 for the same nested object)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your mapping but assuming that `school` is mapped as text and keyword this should work:

```
{
    "query" : { 
        "bool" : { 
            "must" : [
                {"term" : {"user.age" : "29"}},
                {"term" : {"user.education.school.keyword" : "STE college"}},
                {"term" : {"user.education.isRecent" : "1"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change above query to nested query with proper path mentioned otherwise result can come from different nested objects (where all conditions are satisfied but each from different objects )